# Why query returns empty collection?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have the following query was built by Laravel:

```
$res = Announcement::whereExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('announcement_category')->join('user_category', 'user_category.category_id', '=', 'announcement_category.category_id')
                    ->where('user_category.user_id', '=', 1)
                    ->where('announcement_category.announcement_id', '=', 'announcements.id');
            });

dd($res->get());
```

The code above gives me empty collection: `dd($res->get());`.

The plain SQL code of this query is:

```
    select * from `announcements` where exists (select 1 from
 `announcement_category` inner join `user_category` on 

`user_category`.`category_id` = `announcement_category`.`category_id` where `user_category`.`user_id` = 1 

and `announcement_category`.`announcement_id` = announcements.id) 

and `announcements`.`deleted_at` is null
```

If execute this directly in MySQL, I get two result rows.

But why `dd($res->get());` retuns me empty?

Comment: Why did you use `DB::raw(1)` in SELECT clause?

Comment: If to use `*` result is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a whereExists in eloquent model... try this:

```
$res = DB::table('announcement')->whereExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('announcement_category')->join('user_category', 'user_category.category_id', '=', 'announcement_category.category_id')
                    ->where('user_category.user_id', '=', 1)
                    ->where('announcement_category.announcement_id', '=', 'announcements.id');
            })->get();
```

Comment: There it is: [link](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereExists)